# Rails Routing like http:://host.com/controller-action-controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, delimiter, divider

I try to create URL with another divider, not '/', like '-'

from http://host.com/category/food  =>  **http://host.com/category-food**

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work in Rails 3.0 and higher:

```
 get 'category-:id' => 'categories#show', :as => 'show_category'
```

Then you could link to it using `<%= link_to 'Category', show_category_path(category) %>`

Answer (score 1):

Match `'/category-food'` to: `'category#food'`.